# Integrating OpenStack Dashboard inside a Web App

Tags: web-applications, integration, openstack

I have been using OpenStack4j API to access and manage the OpenStack cloud at my work place.

My requirement is to **integrate OpenStack** with an application (**business application** to be specific). What I would want to do is allow access to OpenStack cloud through my application (Web application) i.e., When a user logs in to my app, he can see something like a Dashboard tab inside my app (assume). When he clicks on Dashboard, the OpenStack **Dashboard after-sign-in page** should appear (i.e, *we are bypassing the Dashboard log in*).

Here we are validating the user with the same credentials (as my app) to allow access to OpenStack cloud. For this, I will store all OpenStack user credentials in the same database as my app. If the log in succeeds (**my app user is also an OpenStack user**), the Dashboard page should appear in my app itself. By this, the user doesn't need to authenticate himself twice and also the OpenStack Dashboard loads in my app environment and the user feels like he is accessing the cloud from my app.

I want to know if it is actually possible to integrate Dashboard inside my Web app. Does OpenStack support this and please tell me if OS4j/jclouds has any API to achieve this.

Sorry if it is a dumb question, but am trying to implement this idea. Looking forward to some help.

Thanks,
Shaileshwar

Comment: maybe this would be helpful: http://oauth.net/2/

Comment: Thanks, I'll go through it.

Comment: @despina If you have an idea of OpenStack, please tell me if this is possible: I want to know if I can modify OpenStack Dashboard code to suit my requirement (i.e., auto login OpenStack Dashboard from my Web app). That is, can I embed some JavaScript code inside Dashboard source (at a suitable place) that fills in OpenStack username and password (coming from my business app when I redirect to Dashboard page) and clicks on "Sign In" automatically and takes the user to Dashboard-after-sign-in page?? This happens in a span of seconds and the user doesn't really feel this transition between pages.

Comment: Might be posible if you know python and have access to the openstack dashboard code. The plugin I gave you earlier does exactly the oposite then you intent: you create a script that would actually use this third-party (oauth openID) to authenticate for you. I don't know what server-side programming language you use so I'm not sure I'm able to help further. You can find here some libraries for different languages, maybe it helps: http://openid.net/developers/libraries/ Also take a look here: http://openid.net/connect/

Comment: I did have a look at the Dashboard code. But it's really huge. I couldn't exactly figure out where to embed my code for auto-login. And my Web app is written in ASP.NET. Thanks for the help though.